# Is a payment returned through horizon api call: "Payments for Account" always "confirmed"?

Tags: transactions, horizon

Is a payment returned through horizon api call: "Payments for Account" always "confirmed"?

In comparison to Ripple a transaction could be returned but not validated yet. Is Horizon filtering this out for us?

Answer (score 3):

As of now (August 2018), **yes**. All transactions and operations (including `payments`/`path_payments`) you can see in Horizon are included in the ledger thus confirmed.

However there are [plans](https://github.com/stellar/go/issues/309) to include failed transactions in Horizon DB too. This will likely change in a backward-compatible way but please track release notes for changes.